# PHP MongoDB Driver - Remove array key inside document

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, key, pecl

I'm trying to remove a specific `array key` from my `MongoDB document`.

#### Structure

```
{
    "_id": "5b4d2548d6bd1de5ba2a7180",
    "Fruits": {
        "Apple": [{
                "weight": "0.502",
                "quantity": 1000,
                "ts": 1531870931
            },
            {
                "weight": "0.0334",
                "quantity": 345,
                "ts": 1531870931
            }
        ],
        "Banana": [{
            "weight": "0.302",
            "quantity": 10,
            "ts": 1531870931
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to remove the element `Apple` from the `database`.

I found quite similar solutions, but they are all removing one element(s) of an `array` (like one entry in `Apple`).

There is always only one `document` inside my `collection`.

#### PHP Code (not working)

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
$bulk->update(array(), 
              array('$pull' => array("Fruits" => array("Apple"))),
              ["limit" => 1, '_id' => -1, 'upsert' => true]);

$result = $this->db->executeBulkWrite($db . '.' . $collection, $bulk);
```

#### Response

0 Modified, Updated, Deleted or Added entries; unchanged `DB`

#### Expected Result

```
{
    "_id": "5b4d2548d6bd1de5ba2a7180",
    "Fruits": {
        "Banana": [{
            "weight": "0.302",
            "quantity": 10,
            "ts": 1531870931
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `$bulk->update(array(), array('$unset' => array("Fruits.Apple" => "")),
              ["limit" => 1, '_id' => -1, 'upsert' => true]);` More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

Comment: Super awesome. Worked! Please post it as answer so you get the creds. Thanks